# Normalized table structure Vs Flat table structure

Tags: report, database-normalization

There is a debate in our company for flat table structure vs normalized table structure.
As of now, we do believe that we have a normalized database and application is working well with it.
But, reporting is done on client side by a IT guy as there are some ad-hoc reports are generated time to time.
Sometimes he is worried as he cannot extract details simply as from a flat table structure.
He has escalated to the management and they are also in an impression that high normalized database is not really useful.

How can we defend the normalized database vs flat table structure for this context. Anyone had this experience before.

Comment: We can't answer without more details. Even if we knew exactly what the two design choices were, we have no way to choose "cannot extract details [as] simply" vs otherwise. You would need to give us the arguments. What is the *business cost* of each option? Please read [ask]. This seems to vague & broad. PS 1, What does "flat" mean, other than "one table"? A table has as many dimensions as columns. Pictures on paper & screens are flat. 2.  Normalization does not change the query results you can get, it just changes the queries you write to get them. It simplifies updates.

Comment: Just to clarify: Your "cannot extract details simply as from a flat table structure" is slightly ungrammatical. Do you mean "cannot extract details as simply as from a flat table structure"? Ie he wants a flat design (whatever that means)? And management agrees with him? But "we"--which includes you--support normalization? (Whatever you mean by [*that*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097).) PS There are literally dozens of introductory information modeling & database design textbooks online free from which you could quote the reasons for normalization to 1st & higher NFs.)

Comment: "Sometimes he is worried as he cannot extract details simply as from a flat table structure." If he can't write SQL joins, he *should* be worried. Either teach him how to do his job, or give the job to someone else. (Both those are management issues, not technical issues.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its a debate of normalization vs de-normalization. Was managed to explain the benefits of normalization and propose views to use for reporting.

Problem solved as of now.